# ERB Syntax Errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

Is there any reason why this is returning a syntax error?

```
<%= link_to(post), :confirm => 'Are you sure?', method: :delete, :remote => true, do %>
  <div>Delete</div>
<% end %>
```

This is the error I get:

```
syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting keyword_end
```

I need to have `:remote => true` on the link as I'm using a Ruby gem to display a lightbox.

### Update

I've also tried removing the comma before the `do` but I get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

1. You have only parenthesised one of the arguments to the `link_to` function.
2. You have a trailing comma before the `do` (as Dave noted).

You could have it with parentheses:

```
<%= link_to(post, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete, remote: true) do %>
   <div>Delete</div>
<% end %>
```

or without

```
<%= link_to post, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete, remote: true do %>
   <div>Delete</div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Ah, +1; I totally missed that :/